# Linking error. I don't know what I'm missing

Tags: c++, linker

I'm learning programming from Stroustrup's, Programming: Practices & Principles 2nd ed.  From chapter. 6.3.4, I'm using the following code from the book and get the "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Token{            //User-defined type with 2 members: Token.
    public:
        char kind;      //Member 'kind'. It has a char type.
        double value;   //Member 'value'. It has a double type.
};

Token get_token();  //Created a BLANK function of Token type to read cin input.
vector<Token> tok;  //Tokens will be placed inside vector 'tok'.    

int main() 
{
    while(cin){
        Token t= get_token();   //t from input.
        tok.push_back(t);   //Value in t is pushed back in the vector.
    }
    for(int i=0;i<tok.size();++i){  //i= 0 until less than size of vector, add 1.
        if(tok[i].kind=='*'){       //Finds '*'.
            double d=tok[i-1].value*tok[i+1].value; 
            //Evaluates object before '*', multiplied by object after it.
            //Now what?
        }
    }
}
```

The 'std_lib_facitilies.h' doesn't fix the problem. For function 'get_token();', am I missing any linking or is it that I can't leave the function blank (as written in the book)? I'm new to programming and any help will be appreciated. I'm using Clang set to: c++11, libc++.
Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "get_token()", referenced from:
      _main in 6-5f59e7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I think `get_token` is a function *you* are supposed to implement.

Comment: So where is your `get_token()` function?

Comment: *or is it that I can't leave the function blank* -- You don't have any function, let alone a blank one.  You *declared* a function, but did not implement it.  If you want you can leave the *implementation* of the function to have an empty body (or near empty body).  `Token get_token() {  return Token(); }`

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the clarification.  I wish the book made that clear.  Also, do you recommend any books on programming for COMPLETE novices like me? I feel this book assumes that I know things. No way I would have figured that on my own. Thanks again.

Comment: No book can give you experience.  But some things should be common sense - just as this.  Where shall the computer know your `get_token()` function from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement get_token().  In your case I'd try to do this within a constructor, like this:

```
class Token            //User-defined type with 2 members: Token.
{
    public:
        Token(std::istream& inputstream)
        {
            kind << inputstream;
            value << inputstream;
        }
        char kind;      //Member 'kind'. It has a char type.
        double value;   //Member 'value'. It has a double type.
};
```

Then you could write `Token t(cin);` instead of `Token t = get_token();`

But still I wouldn't like this implementation.  To make `vector<Token>` work well, it should have a move constructor.  That would enable you to write `while(cin) tok.push_back(Token(cin));`.